# How do i add a custom CSS stylesheet in Magento?

Tags: php, css, magento

I've been trying to link a custom CSS style-sheet in my Magento theme, but it's not applying the CSS and I'm getting an error in the Chrome Console with a Syntax error: Unexpected * ..? I guess it's misinterpreting the CSS for a JS file but I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo 
 $this->getSkinUrl('css/custom.css') ?>"</script>
```

Comment: **Duplicate**  [Add css to head from template file in Magento][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739793/add-css-to-head-from-template-file-in-magento

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use it for one time in a .PHP file simply use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('customstyle.css') ?>" />
```

And BTW: Don't use a script tag for a stylesheet.

If you want to use the stylesheet a lot more. Then you have to make a block in your layout.xml

Comment: A derp my bad, didn't even see it. It was sepose to be a `<link>`  tag ofcourse.

Comment: If this helped you please mark my answer as best :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it in your themes 'page.xml', which should be here;

```
MAGE ROOT /app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/layout/page.xml
```

Where XXX/YYY are the path to your theme.

Within this file, find this block;

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
```

And add your css like this;

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
```

Refresh your cache afterwards - including the css/js cache if you have merge enabled.

Comment: I'm kind of a Magento newbie but it seems to work fine in the head.phtml. Why should i add the custom CSS in the page.xml? I'm not trying to start a  fight or something, i want to get to know Magento better and learn from this.

Comment: hi no problem , this is just the standard way to add css/js to your magento themes.  This way you can also exclude them from certain pages if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

remove (script) tag from the code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('custom.css') ?>" />
```

Comment: @Thijs Kempers-from where i copied ?